# Python newbie trying to recursively generate a pattern of numbers

Tags: python, design-patterns, recursion

I need to write a function that generates these patterns:

```
>>> pattern(1)
1
>>> pattern(2)
 1
121
 1
>>> pattern(3)
  1
 121
  1
12321
  1
 121
  1
```

This is what I have tried:

```
def pattern(n):
    if n>=1:
        pattern(n-1)
        print(n,end='')
        pattern(n-1)
```

and then I tried to iterate over it using:

```
>>>for i in range(3):
        pattern(i)
        print()

1
121
```

Can anyone help me understand this concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to pass on some kind of *indentation* to the recursive calls. Each recursive call needs to print a *whole line*, not just part of the middle line.

So for `2`, you want to print:

- The pattern for 1, indented once.
- The numbers 1 and 2 and 1, not indented.
- The pattern for 1, indented once.

But for `3`, you want to:

- The pattern for 2, indented once, see above.
- The numbers 1 and 2 and 3 and 2 and 1, not indented.
- The pattern for 2, indented once, see above.

The indentation goes up by one each time you pass on the recursive call then, and you'd end the recursion when the number is 0:

```
def pattern(num, indent=0):
    if not num:
        return
    pattern(num - 1, indent + 1)
    print(' ' * indent, end='')
    print(''.join(map(str, range(1, num))) + 
          ''.join(map(str, range(num, 0, -1))))
    pattern(num - 1, indent + 1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> pattern(1)
1
>>> pattern(2)
 1
121
 1
>>> pattern(3)
  1
 121
  1
12321
  1
 121
  1
>>> pattern(4)
   1
  121
   1
 12321
   1
  121
   1
1234321
   1
  121
   1
 12321
   1
  121
   1
```

Comment: Nice answer Marty, but I'm afraid *if* the OP wants `1`,`121`,`1`,`12321`,`1`,`1234321`... and so on for `num` = `4`.

Comment: @BhargavRao: not sure what you are saying here. The pattern is a common one, see [Koch Snowflake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake) for the general principles.

Comment: Aw! Oops, Sorry then. I thought he wanted a simple diamond pattern as he mentioned he was a newbie. (*not sure what you are saying here* ... I was just mentioning that he might have not wanted `121` in the 6th and 10th line. However I am wrong, as I was not aware of Koch Snowflakes)